# Why can't I get the custom font from the resources?

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, xaml, resources

I have a library where contains a ThemeResources file, where contain styles.

[image]

In Fonts folder, I have a font file BuxtonSketch.ttf. Build Action is as RESOURCE

[image]

In ThemeResources, I've defined the font:

```
<FontFamily x:Key="FontFamily-Sketch">pack://application:,,,/Resources/Fonts/#Buxton Sketch</FontFamily>

<Style x:Key="TextNormalStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource FontFamily-Sketch}" />
</Style>
```

And since my UserControl called ProblemUserControl, I invoked but is not working

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Resources/ThemeResources.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="La pelicula PROMETHEUS!" Style="{StaticResource TextNormalStyle}" />
</Grid>
```

What could be happening?

Comment: Where is TextNormalStyle defined?

Comment: @ShawnKendrot Ups, I forgot that but I've added. Sorry for that!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This blog](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/silverlight-3-custom-fonts) and [this blog](http://agkdesign.wordpress.com/2008/08/20/silverlight-custom-fonts-how-to-and-issues/) both use the following syntax to use a custom font

Blog 1:

```
<TextBlock Text="SOTC Custom Fonts!" FontFamily="VINERITC.TTF#Viner Hand ITC"/>
```

blog2:

```
<TextBlock Text="Gothic" FontFamily="./GOTHIC.TTF#Century Gothic"/>
```

So for you I would think it would be

```
<TextBlock Text="Buxton" FontFamily="BuxtonSketch.TTF#Buxton Sketch"/>
```

Or for your style

```
<Style x:Key="TextNormalStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="BuxtonSketch.TTF#Buxton Sketch" />
</Style>
```

You may need to include the folder location, but not sure

```
<TextBlock Text="Buxton" FontFamily="Resources/Fonts/BuxtonSketch.TTF#Buxton Sketch"/>
```

Comment: I've been struggling with this problem so many times. Thanks to your answer, I've just figured out the key was to **add the name of the file** just before the hash sign.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can add the fonts to .zip file and access like this:

```
<Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="../Resources/Fonts/Fonts.zip#BuxtonSketch"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just spent a whole day researching this problem. When copying the fonts into the project, make sure Visual Studio set the `Build Action` of these items to `Resource`. All I had to do was change this in the dropdown.